# Capturar o nome do usuário logado no Windows pelo IE 11

Tags: php, javascript, html

Preciso de um código que capture o nome do usuário logado no windows. 
Sei que é possível fazer pelo *ActiveX*, porém só funciona para versões do IE 7 para baixo.

Também estou ciente que existem funções em java como o `getProperty()` que captura o nome de usuário, porém precisava do código em HTML, JavaScript ou PHP (desde que capture a informação da maquina do usuário e não do servidor).

Obs: O código não precisa rodar em todos browsers, só no IE11 é suficiente.

Answer (score 3):

Segundo a documentação do objeto [ActiveXObject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Microsoft_Extensions/ActiveXObject) esse objeto é suportado pelas versões 6, 7, 8, 9 10 e 11 do **IntenetExplorer**.

```
//JavaScript
var WinNetwork = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Network");
alert(WinNetwork.UserName);
```

Aqui a foto do código rodando no IE11 no Windows 10.

[image: Código sendo executado no IE11]

Comment: @LipESprY: Ficou boa a edição, eu agradeço, porém se eu executar o código na página ele passa por um proxy que não suporta o Objeto em questão.

Comment: É, coloquei no snipper **só para usuários do IE**. Se não funciona, é justo tirar do snippet! Qualquer não concordância, pode reverter lá na [revisão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/368870/revisions)! ;D

Comment: Realmente funciona no IE11, porém o activeX tem que estar habilitado e muitos usuários não tem privilégios para isto(computador corporativo). Estou tentando capturar pelo AD, sugestões e ideias são bem vindas.

Comment: @OEstudante: Eu nunca os tentei em server side, mas tenta esse comandos em PHP `<?php echo get_current_user(); ?>` e `<?php echo getenv("username"); ?>`, vai que funcionam.